# PHP and HTML: socket_connect() [function.socket-connect]: unable to connect

Tags: php, html, connection

I am working on a php file that connects to my game server and executes a command. The users enter their username on a HTML form that sends them and the username to a php file that connects to the server. The port is forwarded and the server is ready to receive the info, but I keep getting this error:

Warning: socket_connect() [function.socket-connect]: unable to connect [110]: Connection timed out in /home/moocraft/public_html/test/vote.php on line 8
error: could not connect to host

Here is the HTML file:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="vote.php" method="post">
Minecraft Username: <input type="text" name="fname" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the PHP file:

```
<?php
 $HOST = "207.210.254.141"; //the ip of the bukkit server
 $password = "examplepassword1";
 $player = $_POST["fname"];
 //Can't touch this:
 $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
 or die("error: could not create socket\n");
 $succ = socket_connect($sock, $HOST, 4445) 
 or die("error: could not connect to host\n");
 //Authentification
 socket_write($sock, $command = md5($password)."<Password>", strlen($command) + 1)
 or die("error: failed to write to socket\n");
 //Begin custom code here.
 socket_write($sock, $command = "/Command/ExecuteConsoleCommand:give $player 264 5;", strlen($command) + 1) //Writing text/command we want to send to the server
 or die("error: failed to write to socket\n");
 socket_write($sock, $command = "$player voted for MOOcraft and earned 5 diamonds. Vote at moocraft.org;", strlen($command) + 1)
 or die("error: failed to write to socket\n");
 ?>
```

I can't figure out why I keep getting this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: from the command line, can you `telnet 207.210.254.141 4445`? This is a good easy test of whether your port forward is working. If this also cannot connect, it suggests a firewall is blocking it or the port is not forwarded correctly.

Comment: I'm guessing firewall rule on your system is restricting you.

Comment: also, if you use [`fsockopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) you can achieve the same thing but your code will be more portable - the sockets extension is not available everywhere.

Comment: make sure you have the port number correct.  does this work on a different server?  do you have xampp/wamp/mamp on a localhost where you could test?

Comment: FYI, I was able to use that telnet command from my mac to connect successfully.

Comment: I could connect with terminal, and the code above does work, that is what came with the plugin, but I modified it with my info. I'm just having connection issues. Do you think it's the server's firewall or the website's?

Comment: Hmmm, where is the connection handle from `fsockopen`? And you don't normally need the length field for `fwrite`.

Comment: What should I have? I'm new to php, so I probably sound like a 5 year-old...

Comment: Should I go back to socket_create? I changed it to fsockopen

Comment: That's basically the same function. Won't make a difference. You need to debug with `exec("telnet ...");` etc. if that really works from your website server. Testing from home will not confirm that you have free firewall passage.

Answer (score 0):

Try something simple like:

```
$fp = fsockopen("207.210.254.141", 4445, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)
\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: 207.210.254.141\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

And see what do you get, it might be due to the reason that your server is taking too long to respond

Comment: Still got the connection timed out

Comment: Try using some other host, like google.com and see if you can get something without error...

Comment: It took me to google with the logo gone and a bunch of nonsense on the top of the page.