# PHP - fsockopen() Connection timed out

Tags: java, php, minecraft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP and HTML: socket_connect() [function.socket-connect]: unable to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455391/php-and-html-socket-connect-function-socket-connect-unable-to-connect)

I am using PHP to connect to a server running a Java .jar. I have a plugin installed that allows connections from an outside PHP file. I keep getting connection timed out errors. It was working fine last night, not sure what changed. The port 4445 is forwarded, I can connect to it through telnet, and I allowed my website's IP in my server's firewall.

You can view the PHP code here:
http://pastebin.com/PLAfApdT

```
<?php
 $HOST = "207.210.254.141"; //the ip of the bukkit server
 $password = "examplepassword1";
 $player = $_POST["fname"];
 if (empty($player)) {
     sleep(0);
     printf("<script language = 'javascript'>history.go(-1)</script>");}
 else {
 //Can't touch this:
 fsockopen($HOST, 4445)
 or die("error: could not connect to host\n");
 //Authentification
 fwrite($command = md5($password)."<Password>", strlen($command) + 1)
 or die("error: failed to write to socket\n");
 //Begin custom code here.
 fwrite($command = "/Command/ExecuteConsoleCommand:give $player 264 5;", strlen($command) + 1)
 or die("error: failed to write to socket\n");
 fwrite($command = "/Command/ExecuteConsoleCommand:say $player voted for MOOcraft and earned 5 diamonds. Vote at moocraft.org;", strlen($command) + 1)
 or die("error: failed to write to socket\n");
 echo "Thanks for Voting! You can vote again in 24 hours and recieve more diamonds!";}
?>
```